# Issues with Unity NavMesh Links During Runtime

Tags: unity, navmesh, navmeshsurface

I'm pretty new to gamedev, so please bear with me.

So the end goal here is to have some platforms that spawn in, and the player has to stay on the platforms to stay alive, while an enemy roams the entire screen (Unaffected by gravity), trying to kill/knock the player off the platforms.

The current setup I have is each platform has a NavMesh, and 4 links (1 per side). The NavMesh is re-baked whenever a new platform spawns. However, when I do this, the enemy has some very weird behavior, getting stuck, and teleporting around:[image: This is my 'level scene', where the movement isn't working properly, nor is the healthbar for some reason]

[image: This is the platform pre-fab, it has 4 links and a navmesh]

I've tried using a giant NavMesh plane for the enemy, that the player would be unaffected by, but that didn't work too well either. (Though I'm open to any ideas!)

Here is a clip of the same project in my Testing scene, where the healthbar and enemy movement are working as intended:[image]

I'm sure that I'm just doing something simple wrong, but any help would be really appreciated! Also if you want any more info that may help, its yours!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried telling your agent to stop navigating when you update the navmesh and then restart the navigation? It is probably still trying to pathfind with old data.